# How to unit test KnockoutUtility in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a class that gets knockout messages using the method below:

```
public IEnumerable<Message> GetKnockoutMessages(Data data)
    {
        if(data.Messages != null)
        {
            return data.Messages.Where(m => m.UnderWritingRuleId != null);
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<Message>();
        }
    }
```

So far, i have a unit test that only partially covers the unit test which is below.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void TestGetKnockoutMessages()
    {
        KnockoutUtility knockUtility = new KnockoutUtility();
        IEnumerable<Message> messages = knockUtility.GetKnockoutMessages(MockData.Object);
        Assert.IsNotNull(messages);
    }
```

This covers everything but `return data.Messages.Where(m => m.UnderWritingRuleId != null);`

I was wondering how I would unit test this method to get 100% coverage.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Create fake data source for messages that you know would either match or not match the query in the method under test which would cover at least two test cases for the filter. Provide [mcve] for `Data` and how it was setup for the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unit test doesn't cover everything because you are not verifying all cases. You have to test two logics:

- `if/else` logic
- `Where(m => m.UnderWritingRuleId != null)` logic

Based on this assumption you have to create cases which proof following:

- If `data.Messages` are `null` then you have to verify that method returns new instance of `List<Message>()` because you specified in code like that.
- Next case will be to verify that method returns empty `IEnumerable<Message>` if `data.Messages` are empty (which means this condition `data.Messages.Count() == 0`).
- Next case will be to verify that method returns exact messages which satisfied your condition: `Where(m => m.UnderWritingRuleId != null)`. In other words only messages which have populated `UnderWritingRuleId`.

To achieve what I mentioned you have to create `Data` objects which satisfied this cases. I don't know what is `MockData.Object` but I hope that you included you arrangement there.

Each case should be in separate test method like in following:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetKnockoutMessages_Case1()
{
     // Arrange

     // Action

     // Assert
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestGetKnockoutMessages_Case2()
{
     // Arrange

     // Action

     // Assert
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestGetKnockoutMessages_Case3()
{
     // Arrange

     // Action

     // Assert
}
```

**Arrange** is place where you configuring your mock-ups. **Action** is place where you executing method which you want to test and **Assert** is place where you doing assertion.

Comment: Do you know how I would write a unit test for each of those cases? Sorry I am very new to unit testing

Comment: @Cory Yes, you should write separate test methods for each case. I'll update answer.

Comment: Thanks Kat, it worked using the 3 different test cases.